# Как дать двум <div> один цвет

Tags: html, css

есть 2 дива . Один родитель и потомок. Мне нужно объединить два div в один цвет.

```css
.UpShapka .header {
  margin-left: 25%;
  width:50%;
  height:121px;
  background-color:#373535;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Родительскому div'y дайте желаемый цвет, а дочернему пропишите `inhireit` (наследование).